# after making IK ,it causes some rotating for other bones

Tags: rigging

can anyone help me to know this point---after I make (IK) to bone no.03 with bone 05 main target and bone 06 pole target--when I test rigging in pose mode , I test rig bone 05, it causes rotating all bones especially bone no. 01 -and that mean when I rig ,the arm of character will drape
Note:
I turn off rotation option.

[image: snap]

My file blender:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1taRlAaCu5rD1-VnkliIcl-bdPIgJVRfe?usp=sharing

Comment: hello what do you mean when you says that it "drapes"? To constraint the rotations of the bones you need to select the bone in Pose bone, then Bone panel > Inverse Kinematics, and enable the Limit axis you want

Answer (score 1):

This is how pole target works. It rotates the whole system to reach the target. Take a look at rigging systems, Rigify for example.

Pole target rotates all bones, as in your example:

[image]

But each bone dabbled by two additional bones, which is used to smooth rotation, and twist the arm in the middle instead of rotating in joints.

[image]

Comment: So how can i control bones to stop rotating the upper bone... I apply tutorials and didnt find this point